# Force delete a cloudformation stack in DELETE_FAILED state cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there any option through cli to force delete a cloudformation track which is DELETE_FAILED state. After searching most option rely on console but wanted to get a cli option for this

EDIT: To explain the problem, I have 2 resource attached to the cloudformation, and the second one a rds instance was deleted manually. Now as per event logs I get:

```
DBInstance cf-test-rds-testdb was not found during DescribeDBInstances

The following resource(s) failed to delete: [DBInstance].
```

I tried to run

```
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name cf-test-stack-infr --retain-resources cf-test-rds-testdb
```

but it returned:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DeleteStack operation: The specified resources to retain must be in a valid state. Do not specify resources that are in the DELETE_COMPLETE state.
```

Now I am confused on how to delete this stack through the cli. Because in the resource section the status of this DB instance is DELETE_FAILED and not DELETE_COMPLETE.

Thanks!

Comment: Anything you do via the Web console can be done using the CLI. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/delete-stack.html

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems that it's not the DB instance that is causing a problem. I would use the Console, which will show you a list of resources to retain (although @luk2302 is correct, sometimes the Console makes the task easier).